# Issue with Running Guava

Tags: java, guava

I have a java file Test.java (below) which uses Guava's HashMultiMap (downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). I store both .java and .jar file in "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin" . And then from command prompt, I execute the commands:

> javac -cp guava-11.0.2.jar Test.java

and

> java -cp guava-11.0.2.jar Test

"javac -cp guava-11.0.2.jar Test.java" is executing and producing a .class file. However,"java -cp guava-11.0.2.jar Test" is not executing and giving following errors. Can anybody help me why this happening or a ***step by step procedure*** to run the given code. Thanks.

Error:

[image]

Test.java Code:

```
import com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String key = "hello";
            Multimap myMap = HashMultimap.create();
            myMap.put(key, 1);
            myMap.put(key, 5000);
            System.out.println(myMap.get(key));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By putting Guava on the classpath, you've *replaced* the current directory as the classpath. Do this:

```
java -cp guava-11.0.2.jar;. Test
```

`;` is used as the path separator on Windows (it would be `:` on Unix) and `.` is for the current directory. So this basically says: "Run with a classpath of the Guava jar file and the currently directory, and execute the `main` method in the class called `Test`"

EDIT: I hadn't spotted your second attempt - the problem with that is the use of a colon instead of a semi-colon as the path separator. It would be fine to use `.;guava-11.0.2.jar` instead.