# How to add Jar files in Java in Linux

Tags: java, linux, unix, guava

I have a Java code where I am importing Guava packages. I run it in windows command prompt using following commands:

> javac -cp guava-11.0.2.jar Test.java
>
> java -cp guava-11.0.2.jar;. Test

However, in Linux it is giving error. Can anybody help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What is the error you get? Please specify at least the error or we can only guess based on our experience. Best guess for me is that windows is not case sensitive and finds the jar files while linux is case sensitive and therefor doesn't find the jar files?

Comment: Include the specific error messages that you get. It is _really_ hard to read your mind.

Comment: It's exact duplicate of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9844808/708434) which was answered by John Skeet himself and he mentioned _`;` is used as the path separator on Windows (**it would be `:` on Unix**)_.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue with Running Guava](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844777/issue-with-running-guava)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class path entries are separated by colons in Linux (not semicolons as in Windows)

Try that:

```
java -cp guava-11.0.2.jar:. Test
```

Answer (score 4):

The path separator on Linux/Unix is a colon, i.e. `:`.

So in your case the second command on Linux/Unix would be:

```
java -cp guava-11.0.2.jar:. Test
```